# php foreach go back array missing

Tags: php

I have a string that I have to compile with the previous array values:

```
$arry="<root>
<president><title>apple</title></president>
<president><title>orange</title></president>
<president><title></title></president>
<president><title></title></president>
<president><title>lime</title></president>
<president><title>blu</title></president>
</root>";



$arr=explode('<president>',$arry);
$count=0;
    foreach($arr as $str){  
        if($count!=0){
            $title=explode('<title>',$str); 
            $title=explode('</',$title[1]);
            $title=$title[0];
            echo $title."<br>";
        }
    $count++;

    }
```

Output is:

```
//apple
//orange
//
//
//lime
//blu
```

I need to complete the title missing with the previous value.

I want the result to be:

```
//apple
//orange
//orange
//orange
//lime
//blu
```

Comment: So store previous in a variable and use it if the current one is empty.

Comment: how can I do to store?

Comment: @drg  could you please check my edited solution? I hope it will be helpful for you.....

Answer (score 4):

Its XML, you could use [simplexml_load_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)/[simplexml_load_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) which will parse it directly into a usable object, which then you can loop over, check if value is empty else use previous:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<root>
<president><title>apple</title></president>
<president><title>orange</title></president>
<president><title></title></president>
<president><title></title></president>
<president><title>lime</title></president>
<president><title>blu</title></president>
</root>');

// print_r((string) $xml->president[0]->title); // apple
```

So to loop that and apply lookback

```
foreach ($xml->president as $president) {
    if (!empty($president->title)) {
        $last = $president->title;
    } else {
        $president->title = $last ?? null;
    }
    echo $president->title.PHP_EOL;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/k2Ghq

Result:

```
apple
orange
orange
orange
lime
blu
```

And to convert back into an XML string to store with [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) etc, use [asXML()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php)

```
$xml->president[3]->title = 'foo';
echo $xml->asXML();
```

https://3v4l.org/KEZ2Y

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<president><title>apple</title></president>
<president><title>orange</title></president>
<president><title/></president>
<president><title>foo</title></president>
<president><title>lime</title></president>
<president><title>blu</title></president>
</root>
```

Comment: it is not for me.
I wish I could use the string I have without converting it to xml